# Conditional KinesisStreamSpecification in CloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am new to CloudFoundation scripts and trying to set the conditional attribute for AWS DDB table using the yaml files.

**Tried with below but getting error during the stack formation - Property StreamArn cannot be empty.**

Seems its not allowing AWS::NoValue in this case.

Can we set the 'KinesisStreamSpecification' property itself on the condition?

```
      KinesisStreamSpecification:
          StreamArn: !If
          - ShouldAttachKinesis
          - !Sub "arn:aws:kinesis:SomeValue"
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: when the condition is set to false, it returns error - Property StreamArn cannot be empty. Seems like its not accepting AWS::NoValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `If` should be one level up:

```
      KinesisStreamSpecification:
        !If
          - ShouldAttachKinesis
          - StreamArn: !Sub "arn:aws:kinesis:SomeValue"
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Comment: Confirmed, I had the exact same problem as OP and this syntax worked.